# how to parse complex JSON and show it inside and outside of CollectionView

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

I have been dealing with **JSON** for a month now , getting better day by day. Here is a complex jigsaw I have been circling around. **JSON** return I get is like this :

```
{
"main_content": [
{
  "product_title": "product 3",
  "description": "",
  "regular_price": "320",
  "sale_price": "",
  "product_currency": "&#36;",
  "size": [
    {
      "size_data": "L"
    },
    {
      "size_data": "S"
    }
  ],
  "color": [
    {
      "color_data": "RED"
    },
   {
      "color_data": "WHITE"
    }
  ],
  "gallery": [
    {
      "guid": "http://xxx/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/catagory1.jpg"
    },
    {
      "guid": "http://xxx/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/catagory3.jpg"
    }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Now , here **product_title** , **description** , **regular_price** , **sale_price** and **product_currency** will be outside of array as you can see. For **size** & **color** I need to fetch as array outside of my **CollectionView** , I dunno how to iterate through the array outside of a **collectionView** or **tableView**, coz in those I got an **indexpath** to iterate but I dunno what to do outside a **collectionView** or **tableView**. Finally My Image slider will be inside **CollectionView** therefore **gallery** items needs to be inside that. Here is visual image of my respective page.

[image]
[image]

Now here is the **POST** call using **Alamofire** in my **view**

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

//Error could happen for these reason
enum ProductDetailsManagerError: Error {
case network(error: Error)
case apiProvidedError(reason: String)
case authCouldNot(reason: String)
case authLost(reason: String)
case objectSerialization(reason: String)
}


 // APIManager Class
 class ProductDetailsManager {

 // THE RIGHT WAY A.K.A. "THE ONE LINE SINGLETON (NOW WITH PROOF!")
static let sharedInstance = ProductDetailsManager()

func printPublicGists(parameter: [String:Any]? , completionHandler: @escaping (Result<[ProductDetailsJSON]>) -> Void) {

    let url: String = "http://xxx/wp-api/products/get_product_informations/"

    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameter, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil)
     .responseJSON { (response) in

        guard response.result.error == nil else {
           print(response.result.error!)
           return
        }

        guard let value = response.result.value else {
            print("no string received in response when swapping oauth code for token")
            return
        }

        print(value)

    }

}

func fetchPublicGists(parameter: [String:Any]? , completionHandler: @escaping (Result<[ProductDetailsJSON]>) -> Void) {

    let url: String = "http://xxx/wp-api/products/get_product_informations/"
    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameter, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil)
        .responseJSON { response in

            let result = self.gistArrayFromResponse(response: response)
            completionHandler(result)
    }
}


// Download Image from URL
func imageFrom(urlString: String, completionHandler: @escaping (UIImage?, Error?) -> Void) {
    let _ = Alamofire.request(urlString)
        .response { dataResponse in
            // use the generic response serializer that returns Data
            guard let data = dataResponse.data else {
                completionHandler(nil, dataResponse.error)
                return
            }
            let image = UIImage(data: data)
            completionHandler(image, nil)
    }
}

//gistArrayFromResponse function
private func gistArrayFromResponse(response: DataResponse<Any>) -> Result<[ProductDetailsJSON]> {

    // For Network Error
    guard response.result.error == nil else {
        print(response.result.error!)
        return .failure(RueDu8APIManagerError.network(error: response.result.error!))
    }

    // JSON Serialization Error, make sure we got JSON and it's an array
    guard let jsonArray = response.result.value else {
        print("did not get array of homeFeed object as JSON from API")
        return .failure(RueDu8APIManagerError.objectSerialization(reason: "Did not get JSON dictionary in response"))
    }

    //turn JSON into gists
    //let gistss = jsonArray.flatMap { HomeFeedJSON(items: $0) }
    var gists = [ProductDetailsJSON]()
    let jsonR = JSON(jsonArray)
    let main_content = jsonR["main_content"].array
    for item in main_content! {
        gists.append(ProductDetailsJSON(items: item))
    }

    return .success(gists)


   }//gistArrayFromResponse() function ends here

  }
```

here is my **model** class

```
import Foundation
import SwiftyJSON

class ProductDetailsJSON {

var _product_title: String?
var _description: String?
var _regular_price: String?
var _sale_price: String?
var _product_currency: String?
var _size: String?
var _color: String?
var _image: URL?


init(items: JSON){

    self._product_title = items["product_title"].stringValue
    self._description = items["description"].stringValue
    self._regular_price = items["regular_price"].stringValue
    self._sale_price = items["sale_price"].stringValue
    self._product_currency = items["product_currency"].stringValue

    let sizeData = items["size"].arrayValue
    for itemsIMG in sizeData {
        self._size = itemsIMG["size_data"].stringValue
    }

    let colorData = items["color"].arrayValue
    for itemsColor in colorData {
        self._size = itemsColor["color_data"].stringValue
    }

    let galleryImg = items["gallery"].arrayValue
    for image in galleryImg {
       self._image = image["guid"].URL
    }



}

var product_title: String {
    if _product_title == nil {
        _product_title = ""
    }
    return _product_title!
}

var description: String {
    if _description == nil {
        _description = ""
    }
    return _description!
}

var regular_price: String {
    if _regular_price == nil {
        _regular_price = ""
    }
    return _regular_price!
}

var sale_price: String {
    if _sale_price == nil {
        _sale_price = ""
    }
    return _sale_price!
}

var product_currency: String {
    if _product_currency == nil {
        _product_currency = ""
    }
    return _product_currency!
}


var product_color: String {
    if _color == nil {
        _color = ""
    }
    return _size!
}

var product_image: URL {
    if _image == nil {
        let myURL = "http://www.clker.com/cliparts/d/L/P/X/z/i/no-image-icon-hi.png"
        let noImage: URL = URL(string: myURL)!
        _image = noImage
    }
    return _image!
    }


 }
```

and here is my **controller** class where I am struggling to show the **size** , **color** and **gallery** items from **JSON**

```
import UIKit
import DropDown
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class ShopItemVC: UIViewController , UICollectionViewDataSource,     UICollectionViewDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var contentView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var selectedProductImg: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var backgroundCardView1: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var backgroundCardView2: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var backgroundCardView3: UIView!

@IBOutlet weak var sizeBtn: NiceButton!
@IBOutlet weak var colorBtn: NiceButton!
@IBOutlet weak var productPrice: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var productTitle: UILabel!

// var Title = [ProductDetailsJSON]()

var product_id:Int? //got value from SpecificCatagoryVC
var product_detail = [ProductDetailsJSON]()
var reloadData = 0

let sizeDropDown = DropDown()
let colorDropDown = DropDown()
lazy var dropDowns: [DropDown] = {
     return [
         self.sizeDropDown,
         self.colorDropDown
      ]
   }()


 let CatagoryPic =  ["catagory1","catagory2","catagory3","catagory4","catagory5","catagory6","c atagory7"]
 // let CatagoryPicture = [ProductDetailsJSON]()




 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    sizeBtn.layer.borderWidth = 1.2
    sizeBtn.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor

    colorBtn.layer.borderWidth = 1.2
    colorBtn.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor

    backgroundCardView1.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    backgroundCardView1.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
    backgroundCardView1.layer.masksToBounds = false
    backgroundCardView1.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.2).cgColor
    backgroundCardView1.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
    backgroundCardView1.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8

    backgroundCardView2.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    backgroundCardView2.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
    backgroundCardView2.layer.masksToBounds = false
    backgroundCardView2.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.2).cgColor
    backgroundCardView2.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
    backgroundCardView2.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8

    backgroundCardView3.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    backgroundCardView3.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
    backgroundCardView3.layer.masksToBounds = false
    backgroundCardView3.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.2).cgColor
    backgroundCardView3.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
    backgroundCardView3.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8

    setupDropDowns()





}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height + 40)

    loadGists(parameter: ["product_id":product_id ?? 0])

}

func setupDropDowns() {
   setupSizeDropDown()
   setupColorDropDown()
}

func setupSizeDropDown() {

    sizeDropDown.anchorView = sizeBtn
    sizeDropDown.bottomOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: sizeBtn.bounds.height)
    // You can also use localizationKeysDataSource instead. Check the docs.
    sizeDropDown.dataSource = [
        "XXL",
        "XL",
        "L",
        "M",
        "S"
    ]

    // Action triggered on selection
    sizeDropDown.selectionAction = { [unowned self] (index, item) in
        self.sizeBtn.setTitle(item, for: .normal)
        print(item)
    }

}
func setupColorDropDown() {

    colorDropDown.anchorView = colorBtn
    colorDropDown.bottomOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: colorBtn.bounds.height)
    // You can also use localizationKeysDataSource instead. Check the docs.
    colorDropDown.dataSource = [
        "Red",
        "Blue",
        "White",
        "Purple",
        "Pink"
    ]

    // Action triggered on selection
    colorDropDown.selectionAction = { [unowned self] (index, item) in
        self.colorBtn.setTitle(item, for: .normal)
        print(item)
    }

}



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func loadGists(parameter: [String:Any]?) {

    ProductDetailsManager.sharedInstance.fetchPublicGists(parameter: parameter) {
        (result) in

        guard result.error == nil else {
            self.handleLoadGistsError(result.error!)
            return
        }

        if let fetchedGists = result.value {
            self.product_detail = fetchedGists
        }

        self.reloadData = 1
        self.collectionView?.reloadData()
    }
}


func handleLoadGistsError(_ error: Error) { }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return CatagoryPic.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let  cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ShopItemCell", for: indexPath) as! ShopItemCell

          if reloadData == 1 {


              let myProduct = self.product_detail[indexPath.row]
              self.productTitle.text = myProduct.product_title

          }

    cell.shopItemPic.image = UIImage(named: CatagoryPic[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row])


    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // here you know which item is selected by accessing indexPath.item property, for example:
    let selectedImage = UIImage(named: CatagoryPic[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).item])
    selectedProductImg.image = selectedImage
}


@IBAction func sizeBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    sizeDropDown.show()
    //print("size btn pressed")
}
@IBAction func colorBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    colorDropDown.show()
}

@IBAction func backBtn(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

}
```

There are some other class where I am facing the same issue. Hope If I get this solution I will be able to solve those. Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

First thing to note is that you are returning the size value and not color in the `product_color` variable.

Also when you loop through the arrays in your JSON, you're setting the variable to only be the final value. For example here:

```
let sizeData = items["size"].arrayValue
for itemsIMG in sizeData {
    self._size = itemsIMG["size_data"].stringValue
}
```

The JSON is

```
"size": [
  {
  "size_data": "L"
  },
  {
  "size_data": "S"
  }
]
```

So `_size` is going to be set as `"S"` and `"L"` will never be assigned. I'd suggest changing `_size`, `_color` and `_image` to

```
var _sizes: [String] = []
var _colors: [String] = []
var _images: [String] = []
```

And then when looping through the JSON array:

```
let sizeData = items["size"].arrayValue
for itemsIMG in sizeData {
    let size = itemsIMG["size_data"].stringValue
    _sizes.append(size)
}
```

If I'm understanding correctly, you then want to update your dropdown data when you get the response with the gist.

```
sizeDropDown.dataSource = product_detail.product_sizes
```

Then the same for the other drop downs.

And create product_sizes, product_colors and product_images variables in the model similar `sale_price` and `regular_price`.

Comment: helped me a lot but I am still not in the point . Thing is I want to keep the MVC design pattern , therefore I am using a model, view and controller. If I wouldn't use that I could fetch the **json** in my **ViewController** and everything would be fine , but I want to keep the design pattern. Here you can see I have **append** the array as **let myProduct = self.product_detail[indexPath.row]** . Here is where I can append the array inside a **cellForItemAt indexPath** but how can I append the array outside of it ? I am confused.